# How to open popup window contain UIview or image

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, ipad

i wants to open a popup window on click of buttons.Popup window should contain images or view at runtime.
please help me.
regards
anupam

Comment: You need to give more context...what kind of window ? How should it be displayed ? Have a look at presenting a modal view.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Popup Title" 
                                                message:@"This is pop up window/ Alert" 
                                               delegate:nil 
                                      cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
                                      otherButtonTitles:nil];

UIImageView *tempImageView=[[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(20,20,50,50)];

tempImageView.image=[UIImage imageNamed:@"abcd.png"];

[alert addSubview:tempImageView];

[alert show];
```

Comment: doesn't work on iOS 7 SDK right?

Comment: right..please refer these solutions for ios 7 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18729220/uialertview-addsubview-in-ios7